# Confusing result of NSCalendar.dateFromComponents

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

I try to get the current date without hours and minutes with this Swift code:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: NSDate())

println(components)

let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)

println(date)
```

The result I get with `println` is a bit confusing for me:

```
<NSDateComponents: 0x7fb5ad867700>
    Calendar Year: 2015
    Month: 7
    Leap month: no
    Day: 2

2015-07-01 22:00:00 +0000
```

`components` is 2015-07-02 bute the resulting `date` is 2015-07-01 22:00:00

Where is my mistake?

---

A mentioned with `NSDateFormatter` the result ist fine:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.LongStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

println(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!))
```

Result:

```
July 2, 2015 at 12:00 AM
```

Comment: use dateformatter or instead of calling dateFormComponents convert it in string.default date object will contains time by default in its format.

Comment: My reputation is to low to vote your answer but I marked it with the checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propel is the way `println(date)` works. It used the `description` method of `NSDate` and that returns the data referenced to GMT (UTC). Thus you will see a difference based on your timezone offset from GMT.

In the output "2015-07-01 22:00:00 +0000" notice the ending "+0000" which is the timezone offset and that is GMT, not your timezone.

The upshot is to use a date formatter and specify the timezone, for the timezone of the device you can use the system timezone: `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` or `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()` for Swift.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The `date`ist correct but `println(components)` shows the result with `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()` and `println(date)` use GTM.

I tried `NSDateFormatter()` and get the correct date.

Thanks!